# how to remove unnecessary discover brand logo in cvc field using CardFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-stripe

I tried to generate a card token using Stripe CardFormField and I found an unnecessary brand logo in the CVC field (Discover) can anyone help how to remove such branding logo under CVC field. I am using the

```
flutter_stripe: ^3.1.0
```

below widget

```
CardFormField(
            enablePostalCode: true,
            autofocus: true,
            style: CardFormStyle(
              textColor: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              borderColor: Colors.black,
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              placeholderColor: Colors.grey,
              textErrorColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
```

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since no response to this, I felt I want to share the answer that I got. So I posted the same issue with their respect [git repo](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/786), this is coming for a stripe-android package which is used by [fluter stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe), the error was already updated in [stripe-android](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/pull/5094) so I think we need to wait for the next flutter stripe version. I hope in the newer version this issue gets resolved in a flutter.